# Install latest GTK without building myself

Tags: debian, compiling, upgrade, gtk

I'm using GTK3.4 and I need to update to > GTK3.10 for a theme editor I would like to use.

I've never built something like that from source and the task looks a bit daunting. I've looked at what's available when I type `apt-cache search gtk` but don't see anything that seems to be like an update to GTK > 3.10

I've googled around but only seem to find things that point to tutorials on compiling it from source. If necessary I will follow them but I'm a bit afraid of braking something.

NB: I use Debian-based Kali that's why the GTK appears so outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to compile from sources, the only other alternative is upgrading to the next version of Debian (normally testing/sid) which (normally) has the latest version:

```
➜  ~  rmadison libgtk-3-bin
debian:
 libgtk-3-bin | 3.4.2-7  | wheezy | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, s390x, sparc
 libgtk-3-bin | 3.14.3-1 | jessie | amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libgtk-3-bin | 3.14.3-1 | sid    | sparc
 libgtk-3-bin | 3.14.4-1 | sid    | amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, hurd-i386, i386, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
new:
```

Otherwise, you are stuck to that version of gtk.